# Image to image stylization using stable diffusion

Tags: stable-diffusion

Can anyone tell me how can I make image to image stylization using stable diffusion using python , I do not have GPU , I can use google collab? It would be great if any one can help me with the collab notebook , which consists of code, because I have tried the official collab notebook of dreambooth, but it is not working.

I want that someone can Help me with the collab link.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few projects with ComfyUI and Stable Diffusion running on Colab:

> This is the most powerful and modular Stable Diffusion GUI and
> backend. This UI allows you to design and execute advanced Stable
> Diffusion pipelines using a graph/nodes/flowchart-based interface.

- Colab notebook with ComfyUI and Stable Diffusion by noxouille

https://github.com/noxouille/stable-diffusion-workflows

I tried this one, and it works.

- ComfyUI Colab templates with new nodes by camenduru

https://github.com/camenduru/comfyui-colab

There are a lot of notebooks for Colab in this project.

Comment: This is not working correctly , actually I have to done the stylization on real images.

Comment: I changed the answer, I hope you can achieve what you need via ComfyUI in Colab env.